# New Compass Prefix Mixin Syntax Not Working

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

While trying to create a mixin for `pointer-events` on `compass1.0.0.alpha.16`, [the existing mixin](https://github.com/cange/sass-boilerplate/blob/master/sass/css3/_pointer-events.scss) fails, and reveals that the `experimental` mixin can not be found:

```
@mixin pointer-events($type: none) {
  $type: unquote($type);
  @include experimental(pointer-events, $type,
    -moz, -webkit, not -o, not -ms, -khtml, official
  );
}
```

So after digging through the compass stylesheets, I discover that most mixins use a combination of `with-each-prefix()` and `prefix-prop`.  I tried to emulate that, but failed, with the following error:

> Mixin prefix-prop is missing argument $value.

```
/* =============================================================================
Pointer events mixin
========================================================================== */
@mixin pointer-events($type: none) {
    $type: unquote($type);
    @include with-each-prefix(pointer-events, $graceful-usage-threshold) {
        @include prefix-prop(pointer-events, $type, -moz);
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think pointer-events ever uses a prefix. I've never seen a prefixed version of it.

Comment: Can I Use does not list any browser as using prefixes (neither currently nor in the past) for pointer-events:  http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: @cinnimon - it looks like ``-ms`` is required for IE Mobile.  So how would you go about creating this mixin?